# Pooled MI Variance

Tags: multiple-imputation

I am leaning about multiple imputations (MI), and I struggling to understand the pooled (or total) MI variance equation.  From [Rubin’s rules](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~jls/mifaq.htmll#howto), the expression is: $$T=\hat{U} + \pmb{(1+1/m)} B$$.

**Question:**
Can you help me better understand what the bold part is for and why it is important?

Is the bold part about standard error, degree of freedom, or something else? Also, is there references that could help me understand this?

NA

Answer (score 2):

T=W(hat)+(1+m)-1B is incorrect. What it should be is...

$$T=\bar{W}+B+B/m = \bar{W}+(1+\frac{1}{m})B$$

A good explanation is given in [van Buurens book, page 38](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439868247), although his notation uses U instead of W

1. $\bar{W}$, the variance caused by the fact that we are taking a sample rather than observing the entire population. This is the conventional statistical measure of variability;
2. B, the extra variance caused by the fact that there are missing values in the sample;
3. B/m, the extra simulation variance caused by the fact that $\bar{Q}$ itself is
   estimated for finite m.

This is proven in [Rubin, 1987, eq 3.3.5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471655740)